# iPhone - variables inside methods inside blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c-blocks

we know that we have to previously declare a variable using __block if we want a block to be able to change it. But what if we call the block like

```
dispatch_async(myQueue(), ^{
    [self doStuff];
});
```

is the code inside doStuff subjected to this rule? Imagine doStuff is using variables or properties declared on .h. Do these variables/properties need to be declared using the __block prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think that makes much differnce. I think we can use the instance methods ,and global variables, as we use them in normal functions.

For eg:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        liveImageView.image = image;
    if (image) {
        [self analyzeImage:image];
        currentImage = image; //here currentImage is a global variable, declared in .h
    }
    mod++;
    [image release];
});
```

Comment: so the __block stuff is just for local variables inside a method, not for global variables... thanks!

Comment: Objective-C does not have "member functions".  It has "instance methods".

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the __block prefix on any instance variable to make that method call because the variables used in the method have nothing to do with the block. It is just a method call.

But be aware that the block will retain `self`.